# python floating point errors

Tags: python, loops, floating-point

I came across an issue using Python with floating point errors.  I though it might be useful to mention it here.

I have an external sampling system that records data at 5000Hz.  In order to get timestamps I take the initial time and then add (1.0/5000) to get the timestamp for successive samples.  I noticed very quickly the current time (time.time()) drifted away from the calculated time when using a loop.  just doing the simple calculation there was no noticeable drift - Some code:

```
start_time = time.time()
start_time_test = start_time
#get 512 samples - takes 512*1.0/5000 seconds
for i in arange(512):
   start_time = start_time + (1.0/5000) #5khz

 start_time_test = start_time_test + 512*(1.0/5000)
 print time.time() - start_time_test #no drift
 print time.time() - start_time # drifts
 print start_time_test - start_time # constant increment
```

Now the difference between start_time_test and start_time is not insignificant - It's about 1.69e-5 per block of 512 which very quickly starts to add up.  I'm just surprised at quickly the floating point errors come into play here.  I'm going to investigate the use of the decimal pacakge here to restrict the errors.

Is this level of floating point error to be expected? - Please not that I could be doing something silly and it's not floating point errors.

Comment: Ok fine - Is this level of drift expected?

Comment: [floating point accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) are nothing new under the sun - you might want to use [decimal library](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html)

Comment: Would you expect a floating point error of 1.7e-5 on the calculation in the for loop?

Comment: @RossW Yes I would because 1/5000 is not exactly representable and there will be a big difference in magnitude between `start_time` and 1/5000 which will accentuate roundoff.

Comment: What it boils down to is this. You can calculate `1/5000 + 1/5000` to a high degree of accuracy because the two numbers have the same magnitude. But if you try `10000000 + 1/5000` you will find the errors are much greater because the precision is all consumed by the significand of the larger number. In your code you should perform your summation starting from 0 and then add the summed value to `start_time` after the loop has completed. I hope that helps a little, now that I understand your problem.

Comment: @David: Unfortunately your answer is wrong. In fact the precision of double is almost exactly precise enough to remain under a digit in the last place. While the offset of the code of the poster continually grows, my code down has a neglible offset which remains constant over the whole range.

Comment: @ThorstenS. If you really believe that then you should remove the first sentence of your answer.

Comment: Done that. The difference in scale *might* cause a floating-point number difference so I rechecked it via code to compare the influence of both errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a=time.time()
(a+1/5000.0)-a
#0.00020003318786621094
1/5000.0
#0.0002
1331918373+1/5000.0-1331918373
#0.00020003318786621094
```

The time float is way bigger than 1/5000, so when you add 10^9+2^-4, the 2^-4 part looses precision.

Comment: I see now that the problem is the large difference in values between the unix time and the small increment.  Make perfect sense.  I would still like to have the absolute time of the measurement, however, datetime might be more appropriate to use although I'm interested to see if the decimal package will help

Comment: @Ross Your best bet is to work with relative values rather than absolute values.

Comment: using datetime and timedelta works well: start_time = datetime.utcnow()    t_del = timedelta(microseconds = 200) and then just do start_time = start_time + d_del inside the loop

Comment: It tested the code against my proposition down to look out if in fact significant digits are lost due to the different size. The answer is no, double is precise enough that adding a small and a large number will not result in a loss of precision. So I downvoted your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1.0/5000.0 doesn't have a terminating binary representation.  If you do the same experiment with 1.0/4096.0, you get a difference of zero.  But, in your test, you are calling time.time() with each print, and time.time() will produce a different result each time.  If you want a look at the numerical problems you will have with your choice of denominator, get time.time() out of the picture.  I get 8.743e-16 for the cumulative error for your example.

The point about time.time() being a large number, and thus losing precision with adding small numbers is a correct general observation.  However, I don't think it is the culprit in this case.  Consider the following code:

```
import time
for dt in [5000.0, 2096.0]:
    start = time.time()
    add = start
    for i in range(512):
        add += 1.0/dt
    mult = start + 512.0/dt
    diff = abs(add - mult)
print "dt:%s, add:%s, mult:%s, diff:%s" % (dt, add, mult, diff)
```

This produces a result of:

dt:5000.0, add:1332070890.23 mult:1332070890.23, diff:1.69277191162e-05

dt:4096.0, add:1332070890.25 mult:1332070890.25, diff:0.0

Comment: That is only true is `start_time` is initialised to 0. Otherwise your answer is false. And I believe that `start_time` cannot be initialised to 0. The significance of the error is very sensitive to the initial value of `start_time`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested if adding a large number to a small number is in this case the culprit. The answer is "No", double precision has enough significant digits so that the offset need not grow.

The reason is a common booby-trap which is known in numerical quadrature and mentioned at page 145 in "Real computing made real" from Forman S. Acton

What happens is this: The first approximation is excellent. You get a very small error of 3.3E-8. But you are summing up the errors:

Error 2 is 6.6E-8.

Error 3 is 1E-7

Error 6 is 2E-7

Error 30 is 1E-6

Error 300 is 1E-5

Error 512 is 1.6927719116210938E-5

The correct way to calculate the timestamps with best precision:

```
for i in arange(512):
 time_stamp = time_stamp_start + i/5000.0;
```

It also has the benefit that instead of a continously growing error the differences between the actual and calculated value have random-like differences and cancel out.